# Stripe - Billing section not displaying for events

Tags: civievent, stripe, billingblock

CiviCRM: 5.6.1
Drupal: 7.59
Stripe extension: 5.2

For contributions, stripe integration is working fine but for paid events, billing section do not shows up when amount is selected.

Comment: Does it work if you choose a different payment processor?  E.g. the dummy processor?  Do you have any Javascript console errors?

Comment: Yes it works with other processors like authorize and dummy. I was not able to reproduce it on dmaster demo site. Its likely to be particular to our site, maybe something custom. There are no errors in console.

Comment: Its resolved, problem was a civicrm custom template file needed to be updated. Thanks @JonG-MegaphoneTech

Answer (score 1):

Its resolved, problem was a civicrm custom template file needed to be updated.